# How to set fixed width and height to widgets in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

As a Python newbie I have a problem with the text widget.

Whenever I try to increase the font size of the text widget , the width and height of it changes too.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()

fontsize = 16

def increase_font():
    global fontsize
    fontsize += 2
    textfont.config(size = fontsize)

textfont = font.Font(family = "consolas" , size = fontsize)
my_text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 18 , font = textfont)
my_text.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
my_text.insert(1.0 , "There is a problem")

my_button = Button(root , text = "Increase Font" , width = 13 , font = "arial 11" , command = increase_font)
my_button.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , pady = 5)

mainloop()
```

However , this problem does not seem to occur when I:
1) Use tags in my program
2) Change the font of my text

For example:

```
def increase_font():
    global fontsize
    fontsize += 2
    my_text.tag_add("increase_size" , 1.0 , END) # using tags
    my_text.tag_config("increase_size" , font = f"consolas {fontsize}") # changing the font
    
    # Problem does not occur
```

Or

```
def increase_font():
    global fontsize
    fontsize += 2
    my_text.tag_add("increase_size", 1.0 , END) # using tags
    temp_font = textfont.copy() # creating a new font
    temp_font.config(size = fontsize)
    my_text.tag_config("increase_size" , font=temp_font) # changing the font

    # Problem does not occur
```

The thing is that I don't want to change the font of the text or create a new font , as it causes problems when I implement it on my original program. All I want is to set a fixed width and height to my text widget(and it should never change no matter what I do with it).

This problem really frustrates me a lot and It would be a great help if anyone could fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `pack` the `Text` widget in a `Frame` with fixed width and height and `pack_propogate(0)`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()

fontsize = 16

def increase_font():
    global fontsize
    fontsize += 2
    textfont.config(size=fontsize)

# frame for the text widget
container = Frame(root, width=600, height=400)
container.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
container.pack_propagate(0)

textfont = font.Font(family = "consolas" , size = fontsize)
# set the width and height of the Text widget to smallest values
# and let the layout manager to expand it
my_text = Text(container , width=1 , height=1 , font=textfont)
my_text.pack(fill="both", expand=1) # fill the parent frame
my_text.insert(1.0 , "There is a problem")

my_button = Button(root , text="Increase Font" , width=13 , font="arial 11" , command=increase_font)
my_button.pack(pady=5)

mainloop()
```

---

Update: Using `grid()` on the frame and button:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

fontsize = 16

def increase_font():
    global fontsize
    fontsize += 2
    textfont.config(size=fontsize)

# frame for the text widget
container = Frame(root, width=600, height=400)
container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)
container.pack_propagate(0)

textfont = font.Font(family = "consolas" , size = fontsize)
# set the width and height of the Text widget to smallest values
# and let the layout manager to expand it
my_text = Text(container , width=1 , height=1 , font=textfont)
my_text.pack(fill="both", expand=1) # fill the parent frame
my_text.insert(1.0 , "There is a problem")

my_button = Button(root , text="Increase Font" , width=13 , font="arial 11" , command=increase_font)
my_button.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `grid()` on the frame and button.